# Chrome Postman - how to avoid unnecessary headers

Tags: django, rest, curl, postman

I am trying to build a curl request replica using POSTMAN extension in Chrome

For even a simple POST -d, it adds a POSTMAN token. How can I avoid this? Thanks

```
curl -X POST -H Cache-Control:no-cache -H Postman-Token:494ce988-48f7-67b4-4b8c-90f63c4668f1 -d 'code=newcode' http://127.0.0.1:8000/snippets/6/
```

Comment: You can delte this token in your requests -> see [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36883407/4314952)

Answer (score 2):

In the settings dialog, there is a 'Send postman-token header' option.

This is only available in the packaged app (https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client-packa/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop?hl=en), though, not in the in-chrome version.