# ns.GetCommandSrc is not a function

Tags: reactjs, axios

When I'm connected to the internet, I get error saying `ns.GetCommandSrc is not a function`, but when I disconnect from the internet, everything works just fine.

It should have worked when connected to internet

**Environment:**

- Axios Version : ^0.19.0
- OS : Win10
- Browser : Chrome
- Browser Version : 79
- Additional Library Versions : "react": "^16.12.0"

**Additional context/Screenshots**

[image: Screenshot (119)]
[image: Screenshot (118)]

Comment: Hello, do you have Kaspersky Internet Security? It could cause the issue
https://github.com/OriginProtocol/origin/issues/3607

Comment: it's dependent on other software you are using... like i was using kaspersky..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @mailman_73 said, it has something to do with *Kaspersky Internet Security*, after un-installing it actually it disappeared. But what about with Kaspersky. Somewhere I found a solution that, it has something to do with caching and some caching related problem said, you force requests to pass. So how do you do that in axios. Simply pass an extra header with random value, one great way is to do with `postman-token`, here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/36883407/10305444. After putting a random value in a token, with an interceptor(not necessary - just did it becasue it was fun and better way to do), it didn't appear.

Let me clear a few thing, maybe due to re-installation, something happened, and this bug didn't appear again. So I can't guaranty it. But this solution worth of trying.

Answer (score -1):

Yep had this same thing, Chrome wouldn't work, Firefox did.  Upgraded to latest ZoneAlarm, all good now.