# Cannot load webpage from Postman because of javax.faces.ViewState?

Tags: jsf, http-post, postman, http-request-parameters

I am trying to integrate a web application written by someone else with an API written by someone else.  At the moment I am trying to test one of the webpages using Postman.  When the webpage is loaded in a browser it works correctly.  I have replicated all of the headers and body in Postman, however when I try to launch the webpage in Postman a HTTP 500 status code appears (internal server error).

I think the issue is with: `javax.faces.ViewState`, which is a body key/value pair.  I initially do I get request to the webpage in Postman and get the viewstate:

I tried passing the value: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx;yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy in the body key/value pair, but still I get an internal server error.  I have also checked that the JSESSIONID cookie is identical in the GET request and the POST request.

I have also noticed that if I access the webpage from a browser, then there is a colon instead of a semi colon in the value if that has any bearing.

Most of what I have tried so far was suggested in the answer to this question: [How to programmatically send POST request to JSF page without using HTML form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12175763/how-to-programmatically-send-post-request-to-jsf-page-without-using-html-form)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: html forms are send using body-type form data , are using that in your case in postman ?

Comment: @PDHide, it is loading the webpage but not executing the Javascript onload? tThanks.